# JavaScript Promise: Error message comes after the resolved ones

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm implementing a Generator function that uses a for loop to go through given range of numbers and find the prime ones.

```
function * findPrimeNumbers (from, to) {
    for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        let isCurrentNumber = true
        for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j === 0) {
                isCurrentNumber = false
                break
            }
        }
        if (isCurrentNumber) {
            yield i
        }
    }
}
```

A Promise is called for each prime number and retrieves its name (e.g. when given 3 will return 'three').

My question is why when the number 2 is given and the error is thrown, the message is logged after the resolved ones. My goal is to log it when the number is question is requested.

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'five'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'seven'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'three'
    },
    // Two is a prime number and it will not be found.
    // The error message will come after the resolved ones although it is the first number to be requested.
    // Why?
    // {
    //     id: 2,
    //     name: 'two'
    // }
]

function getNumberName (primeNumber, numbers) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const retrievedNumber = numbers.find(number => number.id === primeNumber)

        if (retrievedNumber) {
            resolve(retrievedNumber.name)
        } else {
            reject(new Error(`The requested number ${primeNumber} is not found!`))
        }
    })
}

const result = findPrimeNumbers(2, 10) // start executing the generator

let isDone = false

while (!isDone) {
    let current = result.next()

    isDone = current.done

    if (!isDone) {
        let numberName = getNumberName(current.value, data)

        numberName
            .then(name => console.log(name))
            .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
    }
}
```

The result is

```
three
five
seven
The requested number 2 is not found!
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want to resolve the promises in order the next you should wait until the previous one is resolved or rejected before you create the next promise. At the moment you basically create them all at once.

Comment: I don't understand why you chose to wrap synchronous code with promises here, it only complicates the calling code here when there's no need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating all the promise at once, so the resolution order is not determined. In order to enforce it you'll need to chain them with something like that:

```
const result = findPrimeNumbers(2, 10); // start executing the generator

checkNextNumber(result)

function checkNextNumber(result) {
  let current = result.next();

  if(current.done) return;

  let numberName = getNumberName(current.value, data);

  numberName
    .then(name => console.log(name))
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
    .then( () => checkNextNumber(result) )
}
```

Which outputs:

```
The requested number 2 is not found!
three
five
seven
```

**Edit**: Use async

If you don't like recursion, you can use an async function (which I assume you can use as you are already using generator anyway). As a bonus, I use a `for of` loop that makes your code more readable:

```
async function checkNextNumberAsync(result) {
  for(let current of result) {
    try {
      let name = await getNumberName(current, data);
      console.log(name);
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  }
}
```